# Passing data from controller request to blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a issue with passing data. 
I create a get request in controller
function path to send data
and blade template to receive some content
but that is not working :D

i try changing web.php few times but, last error i got is non static method

web.php

```
Route::get('/test2', function () {
return view('test2')->with('testGet@show');;
});
```

testGet

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class testGet extends Controller
{
  public function show(Request $request)
  {
    $data = $request -> input();
  } 
}
```

and test2.blade.php

```
<body>
@php
    use App\Http\Controllers\testGet ;
    echo testGet::show();
@endphp
<div class="emptySpace"> {{$data}}</div>
```

I expecting to load blade view with data get from url, i already create view but now i need to pass some data... any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Route**

```
Route::get('/test2', 'testGet@show');
```

Now, you can send variable using compact in controller like this:

**Controller**

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request -> input();
    return view('test2', compact('data'));
}
```

OR

```
 public function show(Request $request)
{
    $array['data'] = $request -> input();
    $array['data2'] = "test";
    $array['data3'] = [32,43,54];
    return view('test2', $array);

    //By this you can send multiple data 
}
```

Now, you can use data in view like this:

**View**

```
<div class="emptySpace"> {{$data}}</div>
```

Comment: same issue. non static method

Comment: after fixing test.blade error gone... but new one come true xD  after type name=piotr  i gto error like: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"    in my blade template offcorse i did something like that $data->name

Comment: @Piter `$data` is an array not collection, You have to access like `$data['name']`

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class testGet extends Controller
{
  public function show(Request $request)
  {
    $data = ['name'=>'apple','category'=>'fruits'];
    return view('test2',compact('data'));

   } 
}

 // in your view 

{{$data}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route

```
Route::get('/test2', 'testGet@show');
```

Goto Controller : testGet ->show

```
public function show(Request $request)
{   
     $data = $request -> input();
     return view('test2', compact('data'));
}
```

Don't import any thing in View.....Just add your html code

```
<div class="emptySpace"> {{$data}}</div>
```